# Bartle or Cohn as a first text in Measure Theory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following texts:

(a) Robert Bartle - Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure

(b) Donald Cohn - Measure Theory.

Which text would you recommend for a student with only a modest background in analysis (say, for example, at the level of Ross's Elementary Calculus text)?  I took a quick glance at both and (a) seems easier (the exercises in particular). Can anyone, who is familiar with both, comment?

Comment: Bartle, the book is expensive though.

Comment: I agree. Cohn's book is very good but IMO not for beginners.

Comment: Cohn's measure theory is a beautiful book.  And you don't have to read the last few chapters.  I would also consider Royden and Rudin.

Comment: Bartle pdf is available here:  https://archive.org/details/BartleR.G.TheElementsOfIntegrationAndLebesgueMeasure_201703/page/n187/mode/2up